# Порядок выполнения функций в PHP

Tags: php

Всем привет. По запросу "порядок выполнения", интернет показывает статьи с арифметическими действиями. А я хочу узнать, в какой последовательности выполняются действия над переменной. Например:

```
strip_tags(html_entity_decode(mb_strtolower($elem['description'], "UTF-8")))
```

По сути, меня интересует, выполняется слева направо (снаружи), или справа налево (изнутри).

В идеале: ссылку на официальный источник, сам "не смог найти / не захотел". :)

Comment: справа налево и сверху вниз.

Comment: Очевидно, функция не может выполниться до того, как будут найдены все ее аргументы.

Comment: *ссылку на официальный источник, сам "не смог найти / не захотел"* - юморист

Comment: @Эдуард снизу вверх

Answer (score 4):

Все функции всегда исполняются изнутри (справа налево). Ведь, если подумать, чтобы выполниться внешней функции, ей нужен результат выполнения вложенной.
Следовательно в строке

```
strip_tags(html_entity_decode(mb_strtolower($elem['description'], "UTF-8")))
```

Сначала выполнится mb_strtolower, затем html_entity_decode, и последней strip_tags

Comment: @Elena, и почему же?

Answer (score 0):

```
strip_tags(html_entity_decode(mb_strtolower($elem['description'], "UTF-8")))
```

выполняется в следующей последовательности:

```
mb_strtolower -> html_entity_decode -> strip_tags
```

Answer (score 0):

Владимир дал исчерпывающий, но короткий ответ. поскольку моя правка не принята, а комментировать не могу, напишу как ответ, поскольку даже не принятые ответы все же читают и может это дополнение будет полезно начинающим.
для лучшего понимания в будущем для всех вложенных функций полезно отметить, что слева сама функция, а справа в скобках ее аргумент. И результат выполнения внутренней функции будет аргументом для следующей внешней. Следовательно, начиная просмотр справа на лево с самых вложенных скобок в строке

strip_tags(html_entity_decode(mb_strtolower($elem['description'], "UTF-8")))

Сначала выполнится mb_strtolower, затем html_entity_decode, и последней strip_tags при условии что никакая из них не вызовет исключение из-за несоответствия аргумента, которым может быть как первичный аргумент, так и очередной результат работы вложенной функции. так же нельзя не учитывать, что при не соответствии аргументов функция может вернуть значение по умолчанию, и это значение будет передано следующей в качестве аргумента.